# facebook connect redirect url suddenly broke

Tags: facebook

Before a minute ago after successful login it redirected to `site.com/home`, but now the link is `site.com/home?state={long-code}6&code={long_code}`

And this is ugly. Any ideas?

**Update**

This is the code i use :

```
session_start();

require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '***',
  'secret' => '***',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
                'redirect_uri'  => 'site.con/home'
            )
    );


    $logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

//session_destroy();

// Show user data
print_r($user_profile);
```

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: There is no error the login is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Update the sdk files you are using.this error comes from this file `base_facebook.php` this is now rectified in the new file.

Use this link for getting the latest SDK [link](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/src)

Comment: I download the files from facebook just before testing it. Version 3.1.1